# Can the FAQ explain what happens at 1000 reputation on SO?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges, site-faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What privileges are given to a 1000 reputation member of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33311/what-privileges-are-given-to-a-1000-reputation-member-of-stack-overflow)

The FAQ states that "Show total up and down vote counts" becomes available when you pass 1000 reputation, but I didn't see any change when I crossed the 1000 reputation mark. Can anybody tell me what changes occurred for me?

Comment: Somebody else apparently asked this same question [a half hour later](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63674/show-total-up-and-down-vote-counts); there's also a good answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that when you click the number relating the number of votes that a question or answer has received you will get to see a breakdown.

So if the total is 2 up votes when you click it - you may see that it has actually had 3 up votes and 1 down vote.