# Show total up and down vote counts

Tags: support, reputation, voting

I just earned my first 1000 rep on SO. The FAQ says that with 1000 rep you can

> Show total up and down vote counts

But I can't figure out how/where I can do that. I don't see any total up/down vote count on questions, nor on answers, nor on users...

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007) from when it was first created

Comment: @Michael, oh, I've even been there! But I didn't notice the "Update:" part...

Comment: Illustrated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33490/confused-about-the-thing-you-get-at-1000-rep/33522#33522

Comment: The answer should be in a FAQ somewhere...or the whole thing made more clear in the "What is reputation?" section of the existing one.

Comment: Duplicate of a duplicate... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33645/how-do-i-show-total-up-and-down-vote-counts-since-im-at-1k-rep

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an example - go to this question 
[Simple SELECT query fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554748/simple-select-query-fails/3554767#3554767)

You will see this:
[image]

then click on the number `4`

You will then see this:
[image]

Comment: This is also described at: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts