# How to "view vote totals"

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show total up and down vote counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63674/show-total-up-and-down-vote-counts)

I just earned 1000 rep on SO. What does "view vote totals" mean and how do I do it?

Comment: Click on the number to the left of the post between the up and down vote arrows.

Comment: @ChrisF, I did not find this on search.

Comment: Don't worry questions don't always show up on a search the first time.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user

Comment: So this does not mean I can see who voted? How to I see that?

Comment: You don't. AFAIK, votes are anonymous in SO.

Comment: @Thomas - you can't see who voted. No one (except perhaps the devs by looking in the database) can see who voted.